# Navigation item being pushed to the left when navigation stack is popped

Tags: swift, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, pushviewcontroller

Having a strange issue here, developing an iOS app that uses a number of navigation controllers. After a number of views have been pushed (segue-wise) onto the stack, the last action when the task is done is to pop the stack, this happens using the method `controller.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false)`.

Now this all seems to work fine, except that sometimes the navigation item titles, seem to be pushed off to the left of the navigation bar. It's almost as if an animation has been cut off short. Sometimes it doesn't happen though, which is the stranger part.

I'm not directly messing with the navigation bar in any way or form, touching the frame, changing positions or anything of the sort.

Here's a picture of what I mean.

[image]

As far as I am aware, "Feed" should be centered, unless this is some new asymmetric design Apple has introduced into iOS8 Swift apps.